# Expectation of random variables

Tags: probability, random-variables, correlation, expectation

a) Show that $E\{X-E(X)\} = 0$ for any random variable $X$.
b) Use the result in part (a) and the following equation to show that if two random variables are independent then they are uncorrelated,
If $X$ and $Y$ are independent, then for all functions $g$ and $h$, $E\{g(X)h(Y)\} = E\{g(X)\}E\{h(Y)\}$

So I understand the intuition behind a); since $E(X)$ would be the mean, the expectation of any given $X$ minus the mean would be $0$.. but putting that into the form of a proof is eluding me..

Any help or guidance is appreciated :)

Comment: One of the most basic properties of the mean is that it is linear. That is ${\rm E}[Y+Z]={\rm E}[Y]+{\rm E}[Z]$ for two random variables $Y,Z$. Furthermore, the mean of a constant is just the constant itself, i.e. ${\rm E}[c]=c$ for $c\in\mathbb{R}$. Try using this to show a).

Comment: @Stefan My initial thought was _E_(X) = μ, so _E_(X-E(X)) would be _E_(X-μ) = E(X)-E(μ) = μ - μ = 0.. I just wasn't sure if that was oversimplifying

Comment: That is exactly how you answer a). This initial thought should have been included in your post. Could you please include your thoughts on b)? This way, it's easier for us to see what is causing you trouble.

Comment: @StefanHansen Corr(X,Y) = Cov(X,Y)/σxσy = E{(X-μx)(Y-μy)}/σxσy. Using the equation given, E{(X-μx)(Y-μy)} = E(X-μx)E(Y-μy). From a), E(X-μx) = 0, E(Y-μy) = 0, so Corr(X,Y) = 0  ?

Comment: Indeed! I urge you to compile your own answer based on these comments and post it.